# Parse Tables in HTML docs and extract TRs and TDs. with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: vb.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I've given a job to convert old data in table format to new format.

Old dummy data is as follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Some text 1.</td>
<td>Some text 2.</td>
</tr>
..... //any number of TRs goes here
</table>
```

The problem is that the new data needs to be in this format:

Some text 1. - Some text 2.
....

Summary of what needs to be done here:

Find all TRs in the table. for each TR find first TD and concatenate with second TD separated by " - ".

I am using HTML Agility Pack with VB.Net.

Please Help.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq and HtmlAgilityPack to get all td's from the table node, get all the InnerText of this nodes and create a new TR / TD.

```
// tableNode is the <table> HtmlNode. If you know where is this table you can use XPath to find him.

Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
For Each childNode As HtmlNode In tableNode.DescendantNodes().Where(Function(n) n.Name = "td")
    sb.Append(String.Format("{0} - ", childNode.InnerText))
Next

tableNode.RemoveAllChildren()

Dim newTrNode As HtmlNode = tableNode.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("tr")
Dim newTdNode As HtmlNode = tableNode.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("td")

newTdNode.InnerHtml = sb.ToString()
newTrNode.AppendChild(newTdNode)

tableNode.AppendChild(newTrNode)
```

I hope it helps